# Dynamically generated ul(s) are not aligning in center

Tags: css, pug

I am stuck at it for very long time and googling did not helped me much. I am generating `ul`(s) dynamically, their count may also very according to number of items found from db.

Here's what its looking like:

[image: screenshot]

The code:

CSS:

```
#container{
 align-content: center;
}

ul{
  display:inline-flex;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

pug:

```
 div(id="container")
         each item in items_list
             ul
              a(href=somelink)

                div(class="image")
                  //- a(href=url)
                  img(src="/images.link", alt="", height="120px", width="160px", class="dp")
                  p(id="title") Title:- #{item.title}
                  p(id="stuff") stuff:- #{item.stuff}
```

I have tried `align-content`, `justify content`, etc. Also I am not giving a property like `margin-left` or something as number of `ul`s will vary. (I want them to get displayed in a horizontal manner.)

Comment: This is rendering invalid HTML. Only `<li>` elements are permitted children of `<ul>` elements. You probably want to start your unordered list before the loop, and then wrap each item in the loop in a list item element.

Comment: I had first done what you are saying , ul-loop-li-stuff(i think thats what you are saying) but then it was putting everything in a single line and so it extended very long that I had to scroll sideways.I have not included that page as I was haivng problem with alignment and the problem I have mentioned in comment ,I was able to solve it with the snippet in question

Comment: Even if it looks right, it's invalid HTML and should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

First think you missed **li** tag which need to list after **ul**

I am not sure which you want but i guess you want this. This is simple demo code

```css
 #container {
        align-content: center;
    }

    ul {
        padding: 5px;
    }

    li {
        list-style: none;
    }

    a {
        float: right;
    }

    div {
        float: left;
    }

    p {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <div>
                    <p id="title">Test Code title1</p>
                    <p id="stuff">Test Code stuff1</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <div>
                    <p id="title">Test Code title2</p>
                    <p id="stuff">Test Code stuff2</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <div>
                    <p id="title">Test Code title3</p>
                    <p id="stuff">Test Code stuff3</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I added li before the anchor tag.Did not worked.As I have mentioned that align content is not working.

Comment: @phantom did you try my code? if work then convert this code as your want

Comment: I tried.Did not worked.Should I put  the whole CSS file in the question if any other part is creating problem??

Comment: @phantom I think you missed something so you can post full code